# Spring boot auto configuration with dependency and without @ComponentScan

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, spring-boot-actuator, component-scan, spring-boot-starter

Spring boot provides [`@ComponentScan`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html) to find packages to be scanned.

I am building a library which has **`@RestControllers` inside with `package com.mylib.controller`**. There are other classes as well with stereotype annotations in different packages.

So, if some one is developing SpringBoot Application with `com.myapp`  base package. 
He uses my library in his application. He need to mention `@ComponentScan("com.mylib")` to discover stereotype  components of library.

**Is there any way to scan components without including library package in `@ComponentScan`?**

As [spring-boot-starter-actuator](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/) expose its endpoints just with dependency, without defining `@ComponentScan`.  OR any default package which is scanned regardless of application base package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a Spring Boot Starter in the same style as the Spring Provided Starters. They are essentially a jar'd library with a a `spring.factories` file pointing to the `@Configuration` class to load with some other annotations on there to provide overriding/bean back off (`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`) and generally provide their own `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Stéphane Nicoll provided an excellent demo of how to build one.

https://github.com/snicoll-demos/hello-service-auto-configuration

It is also documented in the Spring Boot documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

The library approach would also work but I see no benefit in not making it a starter. Additionally for any library/starter I'd recommend dropping the `@ComponentScan` and just defining the beans in a `@Configuration`. This will work for sterotypes like `@RestController` etc. will function as normal if you create an `@Bean` out of it in a configuration.

Comment: Agree with this answer including the mention to dropping `@ComponentScan` in favor of `@Configuration` files with `@ConditionalOnXXXX` annotations. I have also created a blog post about creating a custom Spring Boot starter at http://tech.asimio.net/2017/06/29/Implementing-a-custom-SpringBoot-starter-for-CXF-and-Swagger.html

Comment: Thank you! For me adding `@ComponentScan` caused a lot of weird things to happen in the tests, but adding the controller as a bean in the `@Configuration` class did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot starter are special artifacts designed by Spring and used by Spring.
You can check that in [the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-actuator) that contains mainly a
`spring.provides` file :

> provides: spring-boot-actuator,micrometer-core

I don't know the exact way to process in the same way as Spring Boot Starter but as probably acceptable workaround, you could define in your jar a `@Configuration` class that specifies   `@ComponentScan("com.mylib")`.

```
 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan("com.mylib")
 public class MyLibConfig {
     //...
 }
```

In this way, clients of the jar need "only" to import the `@Configuration` class :

```
@Import(MyLibConfig.class)
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig{
  //...
}
```

Comment: True, It will work, But I need to tell my library users to Import my configuration class.

Comment: I use `@EnableMyLib` annotations where I have `@Import(MyLibConfig)`

Comment: @Saljack where are you getting that annotation from? Only google result is your comment.

Comment: It is a custom annotation.